# Assign key for a hash inside a hash in freemarker

Tags: hash, freemarker

I want to make a new model of an existing model in freemarker to make it easy to use.

My model is something like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "type": "TYPE_1",
        "code": "CODE_OF_TYPE_1"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "type": "TYPE_1",
        "code": "ANOTHER_CODE_OF_TYPE_1"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "type": "TYPE_2",
        "code": "CODE_OF_TYPE_2"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "type": "TYPE_2",
        "code": "ANOTHER_CODE_OF_TYPE_2"
    }
]
```

And I want to make it something like this:

```
 {
    "TYPE_1": {
        "CODE_OF_TYPE_1": "1",
        "ANOTHER_CODE_OF_TYPE_1": "2"
    },
    "TYPE_2": {
        "CODE_OF_TYPE_2": "3",
        "ANOTHER_CODE_OF_TYPE_2": "4"
    }
}
```

As you may know, assigning a key for a hash in freemarker is a little strange..

What I did was this:

```
<#assign preferencesByCode = {} />

<#list preferences as preference>
    <assign preferencesByCode = preferencesByCode + {preference.type : { preference.code: preference.id } } />
</#list>
```

But doing that, it only keeps the last id, so I only have one type..

So then I tried this:

```
<#if !(preferencesByCode[preference.type])??>
    <#assign preferencesByCode = preferencesByCode + {preference.type : { } } />
</#if>

<#assign subHash = preferencesByCode[preference.type] />
<#assign subHash = subHash + {preference.code : preference.id } />
```

But the subHash is not kept as a reference so anything is being asigned to the type..

Any ideas?

Comment: First of all, do you really have to do this in a template? FTL is about printing text based on some data, not about transforming collections/maps to other collections/maps. (FTL doesn't even have modifiable collections/map, by design.) Do this in Java or Groovy etc., but not in a template, because it will be ugly.

Comment: What do you think of the solution I proposed? Anything wrong with it, or just no longer interested?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I agree with @ddekany's comment, here is a solution for your problem.

```
<#function filterList list type>
  <#local result={}>
  <#list list as preference>
    <#if preference.type == type>
      <#local result=result + {
        preference.code: preference.id
      }>
    </#if>
  </#list>
  <#return result>
</#function>

<#function convertList list>
  <#local result={}>
  <#list list as preference>
    <#if !result[preference.type]??>
      <#local result=result + { preference.type: filterList(list, preference.type) }>
    </#if>
  </#list>
  <#return result>
</#function>

<#assign transformedModel=convertList(model)>
```

Comment: I didn't think of that ! That's amazing. Of course as you may know, I decided to resolve it in Java so that the model is passed as I wanted. Anyway, this is what I wanted back then !

Comment: Thanks for returning and accepting the answer although you already solved the problem differently!

Answer (score 0):

A freemarker function returning last hash value from a `root` object in some `path`

```
<#function deepHash obj path>
    <#assign hashes = path?split(".")>
    <#assign value = obj/>
    <#list hashes as hash>
        <#assign value = value[hash]!/>
    </#list>
    <#if value?is_boolean>
        <#return value?c>
    <#else>
        <#return value>
    </#if>
</#function>
```

Exemple: if an object is

```
item 
    {
    "some": 
            {
        "thing": 
            {
                "deep": "Gotta",
            }
        }
    }


<#assign value = deepHash(item, "some.thing.deep") />
${value}
```

will show:

```
Gotta
```